# How to add HTML tag using angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, slickgrid

I am using angularjs And for the grid I am using Slick Grid.

So I add rows inside Slickgrid using angularjs code.

But when I add html code using anjularjs, it does not looks like actual HTML tag. Because it does not call function on click event even though it has ng-click.

My HTML code:

```
div tag
```

my angularjs:

```
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i+=1){
    var deletebtn = $sce.trustAsHtml(input tag with 'ng-click');
    rows.push({id: i, `action`: deletebtn,  'col2':'xyz', 'col3': 'abc'});
}
$scope.dataView.setItems(rows);
```

So my focus is on var deletebtn = ......

How do I need to define it here if I want to call tempFunc() on click event? Please answer as soon as possible.

Comment: sorry my bad.. I mean they are used inside .js file

Comment: Based on code you have provided; I'm not understanding what your trying to do.

Comment: So what you want to do is "dynamicly" insert a input element with an ng-click attribute and be able to make it hit that ng-click afterwords?

Comment: yes. That is exactly what I want, but with the use of Slickgrid.